# How to find if A (1d array) is part of B (2d array)?

Tags: sql, arrays, powershell, contains

I can honestly say I’m way out here.

The scope. I have two databases in which there are tables. I would like to compare the tables to se if they are matching or not.

My approach is:

- get data from db1 table1
- get data from db2 table1
- for each row in db2 table 1 check if that exact row is present in db1 table1

Example:

db1 table1

- id, column1, column2
- 1, aa, bb
- 2, cc, dd
- 3, ee, ff

db2 table1

- id, column1, column2
- 1, aa, bb
- 3, ee, aa

Row with id=1 will generate no output since it is exactly the same in db1 table1 as in db2 table1.
Row with id=2 will generate no output since it is missing completely from db2 table1.
Row with id=3 will generate error since value in column2 is different between the two db’s.

I have managed to extract data from the two db’s and tables and I now have them in two different variables (2d arrays?). Now comes the problem.

When I write the content to host it looks like this for db1 table1:

```
@{id=1; column1=aa; column2=bb} @{id=2; column1=cc; column2=dd} @{id=3; column1=ee; column2=ff}
```

… and lite this for db2 table1:

```
@{id=1; column1=aa; column2=bb} @{id=3; column1=ee; column2=aa}
```

My idea was to do something like this:

```
foreach ($row in $db2table1) {
    if($db1table1.Contains($row)) {
        #all is good
    }
    else {
        #error
   }
}
```

But it don’t work. Ideas?

Comment: Is there a special reason why you're not using `Compare-Object`?

Answer (score 0):

[Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-6) makes this task easier. You can perform a check like so:

```
$check = Compare-Object -ref $db1table1 -dif $db2table1
if ($check) { 
    "Error"
} else {
    "All Good"
}
```

By default, `Compare-Object` outputs differences only indicating which object had the difference (`SideIndicator` property). If no difference is found, nothing is output. You can change the default behavior with `-IncludeEqual` and `-ExcludeDifferent` parameters.